# Magento 2 admin panel is down after changing Base URL

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, base-url, core-config-data

I have changed Base URL secure and unsecure from the backend.
I had the following url= http://subdomain.domain.org/folder (also https) and I changed it in order to have http://subdomain.domain.org/.
The frontend is currently working fine as http://subdomain.domain.org, but the backend for some reason stopped working, and now it trows an error Not Found.

The way I access the backend is http://subdomain.domain.org/folder/admin I did not change the admin url and cannot access to that url.

I have changed all old URL in `core_config_data` table, but its not working yet.

Greetings!

Comment: Did you clear the cache ?

Comment: yes, I cleared cache, upgraded, reindex, etc...

Comment: http://subdomain.domain.org/ It redirects on the https://www.domain.com/

Comment: if I type subdomain.doma.org does not redirects anywhere, just displays PHP version page.

Comment: I have modified it, now if you type subdomain.domain.org it redirects you to https:// subdomain.domain.org , but why Admin panel is not found?

Comment: Some time browser cache also cause the issue, would you change the browser and than test wither its working or not?

Comment: Hello, Its not working, I have tried with Edge and Chrome. If I try to access to the admin it redirects to the website and says whoops, our bad, the page you requested was not found.

Comment: This is what i get if i try to access to my admin panel admin_1r6ktm/admin/index/index/key/b6e408f87aee1353c5b61c71d303a451a1e33a3bfc065d089ed405b3e087075c/

Comment: Let me confirm do you have these url in under store->configuration->general->web->base url  and base url (secure)?
base url:http://subdomain.domain.org/folder
secure url:http://subdomain.domain.org/folder

Secondly what options selected under 
store->configuration->general->web -> base url (secure)->Use Secure URLs on Storefront?
store->configuration->general->web -> base url (secure)->Use Secure URLs on Storefront?
store->configuration->general->web -> base url (secure)->Use Secure URLs in Admin?

Comment: Hello y changed everything back, my intention was to use subdomain.domain.org instead of subdomain.domain.org/folder. Base secure URL and unsecure were subdomain.domain.org, it worked on frontend, however in Backend or admin panel was not found.